# @webroot - how to find out path?

Tags: config, console

Getting "Error clearing cache Control panel resources: Unable to clear control panel resources because the location isn't known for console commands" and the recommendation to set @webroot in config/general.php.

However, when I had previously done that, at least one plugin created a new /www/public_html/ **below** the folder in which Craft sits, and the assets from it weren't accessible in templates.

Is there an easy way to specify the absolute path somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the `@webroot` alias in your `config/general.php`. To make sure the path is always absolute and always correct for each environment, you can use the [`CRAFT_BASE_PATH` constant](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/#craft-base-path).

```php
// config/general.php
return [
    '*' => [
        'aliases' => [
            '@webroot' => CRAFT_BASE_PATH . '/web',
        ],
    ],
];
```

You can find a similar example in the [Craft documentation on aliases](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#aliases).

To find out if the alias is defined correctly, put this somewhere in a template and check the output:

```twig
{% dd craft.app.config.general.aliases %}
```

Comment: I believe I had this, it was what was where '/web' was that created an error - e.g. '/www/public_html/public' was then causing a plugin to create a string of folders called /www/public_html/public inside the public folder.

If my absolute path is /storage/[username]/www/public_html/public where the index.php file sits, was that correct?

Comment: @EmmaSwann Looks correct to me … maybe post your `config/general.php` to see if there's an inconsistency somewhere. Also, it might just be a buggy plugin. What plugin is causing this? To check if the path is set correctly, put this somewhere in a template and check the output: `{% dd craft.app.config.general.aliases %}`

Comment: Thanks - that tag shows what should be there - currently siteUrl is defined to the domain name.

The plugin that I know causes an issue is Blitz Cache - I can see the path to where the cache sits changing in error as soon as the @webroot is defined.

Comment: @EmmaSwann Which command is producing this error? What path are you seeing in the error if you define the webroot as mentioned above?  Also, what is your [cache storage setting](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/blitz#cache-storage) for Blitz?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed your server configuration at all recently?

By "change" I mean add another domain or subdomain, go from staging to production, switch hosts, etc.

It sounds like maybe Craft thinks the document root (what Craft calls the `@webroot`) is one spot, but the web server is setup for something else.

Shared hosting providers that use cpanel for example are notorious for this. Usually the "default" virtual host will expect you to put all your files in a certain directory, usually `public_html` or `www`. This is known as the web server root and that's typically where a static "homepage" is served out of it. In Craft's case, it's `index.php`.

However, Craft expects the rest of application files to live one folder/directory above that web root. Shared hosting often doesn't let you move files above the webroot so you'd need to [move files around](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/moving-craft-files).

I usually test things like this by ignoring Craft for a moment:

1. Create a new file, `testindex.php` and add `<?php phpinfo();` to it.
2. Throw it in the same folder as Craft's `index.php`
3. Visit the file in your web browser.  It should be `whatever.com/testindex.php` if everything's pointed properly.

(If Craft is in a sub folder it'll be at `/subfolder/` instead.)

Two things could happen:

- If you get a **404 not found error** that means the webroot / document root is not where you think it is. Try `example.com/public/testindex.php` or `/web/testindex.php`
- If it **does** work, PHP will spit out a bunch of configuration information that's handy including showing what your PHP environment sees.

Search for `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and it'll show where the "base" of your website is supposed to live. In a default install of Craft, all of the files from the `web` folder go here.

Make sure to remove the testing file after you're done.